# Managing Permissions on web server for image upload

Tags: php, cpanel, image-uploading

I have web server which allows for image uploading. When the user uploads an image, it uploads onto the server but when try to access the file using the browser from other pages it is giving me:

> 403 forbidden

What kind of permissions should the files have for accessing the images publicly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, for reading =). That will be `chmod('0644')` in PHP.

Make sure, that directory, where image files are placed, also is accessible for reading, thus both access rights and `.htaccess` settings grants reading access..

Answer (score 2):

i think the permission code you want to change it to is 0644

Here's how to change the permission of a file with php.
[chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Comment: Thanks @TGammage that really helped me

Comment: YW. ankhzet is right too... be aware of any .htaccess files (both in the current dir and parent dirs) that might restrict a client from getting an image

Answer (score 1):

Try 3-digit `chmod 664` command. The last digit sets the permission for class 'others', which basically encloses all your client-side users. `4` stands for read-only.